# IE 11 support for css grid

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app, postcss, autoprefixer

I'm building a React app created with create-react-app 2.0. I'm also using css grid which is very handy for my needs. For some reason though I need to support Internet Explorer which does not support css grid. How can I configure some kind of bridge (autoprefixer in cra2?)? Do I need to eject cra2 app?

Comment: a polyfill maybe ? https://github.com/FremyCompany/css-grid-polyfill/  demos to check it out https://github.com/FremyCompany/css-grid-polyfill/tree/master/demo/css-grid might be out of date, but IE11 is too ;)  a demo online https://rawgit.com/FremyCompany/css-grid-polyfill/master/demo/css-grid/layout4.html

Comment: Not sure IIUC, but maybe just use a scss mixin that add the prefixes you need?

Comment: @RenanSouza with the prefix, you have an average support (partial support and about an older version of grid syntax) https://caniuse.com/#search=grid , the polyfill might be good enough to not waste time on it. test and keep what works and avoid what doesn't if it really goes nuts ;) Else, on your free time, it can be fun to spend some times there.

Comment: That makes sense, I agree that this is more reliable as well. Good luck with the extra needed work tho, having to support IE is a pain in the ass :/